# Sorting an object based on its parameters in swift

Tags: swift

I have array objects, I want to sort the array of object based on its parameter.

```
class User {
    var firstName, lastName, userName: String?
    var id: UUID? 
}
```

I have array of `userObject`. I want to sort the user based on its `userName` and return the array of `userObjects` in appropriate order.

userArray = [(Shyam, M, ShayamM, 1),(Amar, S, AmarS, 3)),(Prema, A, PremaA, 2))]
    userArray = userArray?.sorted(by: {$0.name! < $1.name!})

I want output like this :
userArray = [(Amar, S, AmarS, 3)),(Prema, A, PremaA, 2)),(Shyam, M, ShayamM, 1)]

Comment: Can you provide sample of expected behavior ?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are all properties optional? An user is supposed to have at least an `userName` and an `id`. **Never** use optionals as an alibi not to write an initializer.

Comment: Quite some mixup here. 1) you sort by name, which is not a property of User. 2) You say: I want to sort user based on its userName. 3) you say firstName "is not swapped". So what's the real issue here?

Comment: The array you provided as an example is an array of tuples and not `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
    var userArray = [User("Shyam", "M", "ShayamM", 1), User("Amar", "S", "AmarS", 3), User("Prema", "A", "PremaA", 2)]
    userArray.sort { (user1, user2) -> Bool in
        if let username1 = user1.userName, let username2 = user2.userName
        {
            return username1 < username2
        }
        return false
    }
```